# Google apps script - Auto Fill Column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

I've just learnt about arrayformula and continue for keeping formulas into new rows, now im trying to get a single string to copy into new rows "N". How can I achieve this?

Basically, i've got some columns with formulas that are copied down using array formula, i've tried to use this to copy "N" into a column which needs to be pre-filled with "N" how it has not work, is there any other ways I can achieve this?

Overall I'm just asking is there a way to fill a single column with the letter "N" using either a formula or a script? If yes how?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have a spreadsheet at hand to try, but try

```
= arrayformula(if(N:N=0;"N";"N"))
```

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way using a script would be like this :

```
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = [];
  for(var n=0 ; n<s.getMaxRows();n++){
    col.push(['N']);
  }
  s.getRange('N:N').setValues(col); // write data in any column, N in this example :-) 
}
```

It creates a 2D array with the right value and size and writes it on the sheet in one single step.

Comment: But you have to keep running it to fill new rows. Its possible to do it with a single arrayformula

Comment: This can be done automatically with a sheet trigger... but the other answer gives the formula approach if you prefer... both have pros and cons... you have the choice ;)

Comment: Voted up - both achieve what I wanted, however the other one does it automatically. Thank you :)!

Comment: yes both are good approaches. in fact beware that array formulas sometimes (but rare) get stuck and stop auto-updating until you click them and press ctrl+something (its a manual task) where serge's approach, tied to onChange, even if it fails once, the next change will handle it.

Comment: This solution is my favorite, remember to use var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('SHEET_TAB'))